# In jQuery I want to remove all HTML inside of a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div and I want to remove all the HTML inside of that div.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You want to use the [empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) function:

```
$('#mydiv').empty();
```

Answer (score 74):

I don't think `empty()` or `html()` is what you are looking for. I guess you're looking for something like `strip_tags` in PHP. If you want to do this, than you need to add this function:

```
jQuery.fn.stripTags = function() {
    return this.replaceWith( this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') );
};
```

Suppose this is your HTML:

```
<div id='foo'>This is <b>bold</b> and this is <i>italic</i>.</div>
```

And then you do:

```
$("#foo").stripTags();
```

Which will result in:

```
<div id='foo'>This is bold and this is italic.</div>
```

Comment: I think he meant removing all content. Still +1 for good answer for future generations.

Comment: Personally I would just do $("#foo").html($("#foo").text());

Comment: He didn't mean if he wanted the plain text result or not, but still this answer worked for me :)

Comment: Great, with some minor changes it also worked great for input-fields. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is just to set the html to the empty string:

```
$('#mydiv').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlJ = $('<p><span>Test123</span><br /><a href="http://www.google.com">goto Google</a></p>');
console.log(htmlJ.text()); // "Test123goto Google"
```

Comment: If text is `<script type="text/javascript">alert('sasa');</script>` it will alert, so it's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function stripsTags(text)
  {
    return $.trim($('<div>').html(text).text());
  }
```

Comment: If text is `<script type="text/javascript">alert('sasa');</script>` it will alert, so it's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a html like this

```
<div class="prtDiv">
   <div class="first">
     <div class="hello">Hello</div>
     <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want all html under "first" div to remove permanently. just use this

```
$('.first').empty();
```

result will be like this

```
<div class="prtDiv">
   <div class="first">

  </div>
</div>
```

for temporary(if you want to add them again) we can try detach() like

```
$('.first').detach();
```