# remove html <tags> from database-driven text within a wmd text-editor TEXTAREA

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

Looking at "[In jQuery, want to remove all HTML inside of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652917/in-jquery-want-to-remove-all-html-inside-of-a-div)", I got going in the right direction to what I'm looking for:

I have a textarea similar to the following:

```
<textarea id="inputPane" cols="80" rows="40" class="pane" style="height:300px;">
<table><tr><td>
 <b>Since your service bureau</b>, xxx is not certified 
 by our company for xyz, your company will need to complete 
 more testing as part of the process.
</td></tr></table>
</textarea>
```

Using this code from the URL listed above, I'm able to remove all whitespace apparently, but am unable to remove the actual HTML tags: `<b></b>`, `<table>`, etc.

```
jQuery.fn.stripTags = function() 
{ return this.replaceWith( this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') ); };
```

What is this part saying?

```
/<\/?[^>]+>/gi
```

I think it reads:

- remove this character `<`
- and remove this character `>`
- and replace with nothing.

Although this is not what it is doing in my code. It seems to strip all the whitespace from the DIV I put it on.

What is the `gi` part? 
And, would you have a good solution to remove HTML tags from a wmd-editor textarea when the HTML displayed is coming from a database?

Comment: `gi` means the pattern is applied globally, and to ignore-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following script to remove html tags from a string-

```
 function removeHTMLTags(htmlString)
 {
    if(htmlString)
    {
      var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
       mydiv.innerHTML = htmlString;

        if (document.all) // IE Stuff
        {
            return mydiv.innerText;
        }   
        else // Mozilla does not work with innerText
        {
            return mydiv.textContent;
        }                           
    }
 }
```

not exactly sure but i think `/gi` part indicates global replace like in `string.replace` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to grab some divs of html and copy them into a textarea. I got it all into one line like this:

```
$('#yourTextarea').val($('#yourTextarea').val()+$('.yourHTMLdivs').text().replace(/ +(?= )/g,''));
```

The `.yourHTMLdivs` is the section that gets copied and stripped. The `.text()` is what strips out the html. The `.replace()` at the end takes out extra whitespace. Doing it this way, your information is all stripped and set to go BEFORE it goes into the textarea.

(I worked this out after reading three or four similar problems on StackOverflow! Great stuff here.)

Answer (score 0):

With jquery more simple:

```
function removeHTMLTags(htmlString)
 {
    if(htmlString)
    {
      var mydiv = $("<div></div>");
       mydiv.html(htmlString);
       retun mydiv.html();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Typo here // more chars