# Formatting HTML within jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string-formatting

So guys, I just want to format a string with jQuery, the string can be with closed html tags `<div><h2></h2><span></span></div>` or without it such as `<div><h2></h2><span>`, or it may contains images such as `<img src=""/>`, but I need to format it to have as result only plain text, I suppose that this can be done with a regex, I googled it, but could not find such an example.

So if you could help me, I'll be very thankful for help. Thanks

An exemple of the string:

```
<p> 
    <span style="color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; ">Преимущества стоматологической установок Anthos</span>
</p> 
<ul class="tech_list" style="margin: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; list-style-type: none; color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; "> 
    <li style="margin: 0px; padding: 8px 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; overflow: hidden; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); "> 
       <img alt="Anthos " class="photo" src="http
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var body;

try {
    body = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().body;
    //In chrome this avoids requesting images in the html
}
catch(e){
    body = document.createElement("body");
}
//this doesn't execute css or scripts
body.innerHTML = '<p> <span style="color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; ">Преимущества стоматологической установок Anthos</span></p> <ul class="tech_list" style="margin: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; list-style-type: none; color: rgb(35, 31, 32); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; "> <li style="margin: 0px; padding: 8px 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; overflow: hidden; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(204, 204, 204); "> <img alt="Anthos " class="photo" src="http'

console.log( $(body).text() );
//Преимущества стоматологической установок Anthos
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/FvBzX/

Comment: Sorry, but not working, I updated my post with an example of text.

Comment: @DenisHoss works fine http://jsfiddle.net/FvBzX/, you are doing something differently ?

Comment: Yeap in jsfiddle works fine, I don't understand where I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".example_1").html( $(".example_1").text() );
```

Take the HTML of the div, grab the text of the div and place it back into the html of the outside containers.

Stolen from [Googled Website](http://frobert.com/en/2011/01/21/strip-html-jquery/)

Comment: This will execute scripts in the html. In chrome it will also request images.

Comment: Your solution working good, but, in some texts there are a little errors, so far your solution it's the best. I updated my post with an example of text.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/653699/1456376

```
jQuery.fn.stripTags = function() { return this.replaceWith( this.html().replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '') ); };
```

Comment: Sorry, but not working, I updated my post with an example of text.

Answer (score 0):

this RegEx should strip all html tags from a string:

```
var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Comment: Sorry, but not working, I updated my post with an example of text.